# Netbeans import projects after initial setup

Tags: netbeans-7

I've just installed Netbeans 7.4, having previously been using 7.2
Like a fool, I accidentally clicked no when Netbeans asked me If I wanted to push my projects and settings to the new version. Is there a way I can do this now?

I'm tempted to uninstall and start again so I can have that option pop up again

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools | Options and click Import...